# How to change wordpress dates to native language (even if the languge not available i wordpress)

Tags: posts, search

I have a fully native language website ( Sinhala ). Content is fine and works with sinhala text. But unfortunately I cannot get the dates to be shown in Sinhala ( in posts new etc). Also I need to get the placeholder text in search bar to be converted to sinhala as well ( When i replace with sinhala text in code, output looks like square boxes instead of letters ).

I came across the WP sinhala translation but it seems to be inactive. So is their is a way to get this fixed ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "When i replace with sinhala text in code, output looks like square boxes instead of letters" - if that's square boxes in your editor, your editor might be using a font that doesn't support Sinhala. If it's in the website when it's displayed - assuming you're using a Sinhala font there - then it's probably because the character encoding got broken somewhere along the way: either in the copy/paste, or in parsing the source files for display: you could make sure you're using UTF-8 both in your editor and as default encoding for PHP. But the easiest way is as a translation, as mmm's answer below.

Comment: Yes i tried mmm's solution and it works really smooth. Now trying to update the .po file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

to use a translation not finished yet, click on "Export" here : 
https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev/si/default . And save the files as `si.po` and `si.mo` in the directory `wp-content/languages` (choose the extension in the dropbox menu)

If there is word missing, you can use Podedit to edit the file and you can also propose your word in the tool translate.wordpress.org

Comment: Thank you mate. it works.   Any specific software I can use to edit the file  with new text ?

Comment: I manage to find this one online https://localise.biz    Should we edit .mo too ?

Comment: I don't know this but I recommand you Poedit wich is very complete to edit the PO file (and creating the corresponding MO file) https://poedit.net/